# .Bat file syntax error

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I am really new with .Bat scripting and I am trying to put together a nested loop process where the script counts how many files are in a "pending" folder if it is below a certain amount it reaches out to a "source" folder to drop a set amount of files. if the amount matches then it moves to another loop where it counts how many files are in "docs" folder, once again if it is below a set amount then have files from "pending" moved over if not then have it go to timecount for 30 seconds and start over from the first loop.

```
 @echo off

 setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

 :: loop1 reads through the pending folder to determine if there are files in it.
 :: if there are the min amount of files the process moves to loop2 if not then it
 :: adds files from the source to the pending
 :loop1

 :: folder names and counts
 set acount=0
 set bcount=2
 set ccount=0
 set gcount=2
 set srcdir=C:...\sourcefolder1
 set dstdir=C:...\pendingfolder

 :: counts files in dstdir and determine if files need to be added
 :: or can move on to next loop
 for /f %%F in ('dir /b %dstdir%') do set /a acount+=1
 if %acount% GEQ %bcount% goto loop2

 ::add files to dstdir
 pushd %srcdir%
 for %%i in (*.txt) do (
 set /a ccount+=1
 move %%i %dstdir%\%%i
 if !ccount! GEQ %gcount% goto loop2
 )
 popd

:: loop2 checks to see if there are any files in the docs folder. if there     is a min amount it goes to timecount
:: if there are not a min amount, files from pending get added to docs.

:loop2
:: folder names and counts
set dcount=-5
set fcount=2
set mcount=0
set srcdir=C:...\pendingfolder
set dstdir=C:...\docs

for /f %%F in ('dir /b %dstdir%') do set /a dcount+=1
if %dcount% GEQ %fcount% goto timecount 

::add files to dstdir
pushd %srcdir%
for %%i in (*.txt) do (
set /a mcount+=1
move %%i %dstdir%\%%i
if !mcount! GEQ %fcount% goto timecount 
)
popd

:timecount
TIMEOUT 30
goto loop1

PAUSE
```

With the code above i get "the syntax of the command is incorrect" Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Quote the arguments in your `move` commands.  If that doesn't help, `rem` out `@echo off` and see which command results in that error.  Also, indent the contents of your `for` loops.  The lack of indenting isn't related to your errors, but it just makes your code easier to read.  Not everything in batch scripts has to be left-justified.

Comment: thanks for the reply - it errors out on (move %%i %dstdir%\%%i) i tried putting it in quotes but it changes the error to "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect". :/

Comment: put echo in front of each destructive commands

Comment: @StevenP `move "%%~i" "%dstdir%"`.  Use the tilde to strip surrounding quotes in case `%%i` contains any, then re-quote explicitly.  If you need more information on using a `~` to strip quotation marks, see `help for` in a console window.

Comment: @rojo That worked! thank you so much